# Property "quote" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance. (Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, java, vue.js, axios

Trying to fetch from the `kanye` api and I keep getting this error

> Property "quote" was accessed during render but is not defined on
> instance.

Here's my code **:**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <i>{{quote}}</i>
    <p>Kanye West</p>
    
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import { ref } from 'vue'
export default {

    setup() {

        const quote = ref('')

        const getQuote = async () => {
            const response = await axios.get('https://api.kanye.rest/')
            quote.value = response.data.quote
        }
        getQuote()
```

`

Comment: Did you get a chance to look into the answer I added ? I hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to return the `quote` from your setup function.

Live Demo **:**

```js
console.clear();

const { ref, onMounted } = Vue;

let options = {
  setup: function () {
    let quote = ref('');

    onMounted(function () {
      // Just for demo I am using the mock api response but you can change it with the actual API call.
      quote.value = 'This is today\'s quote';
    });

    return {
      quote
    };
  }
};

Vue.createApp(options).mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.0-beta.14/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  {{ quote }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
{{quote.quote}}
```

Comment: Hey @Emmanuel Edgan, welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer was flagged for lenght and content. Would you mind improving it?

Answer (score 0):

You should just **return** quote.

```
<template>
  <i>"{{ quote }}"</i>
  <p>Kanye West</p>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
import { ref } from "vue";
export default {
  setup() {
    const quote = ref("");

    const getQuote = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get("https://api.kanye.rest/");
      quote.value = response.data.quote;
    };

    getQuote();

    return {
      quote
    }
  },
};
</script>
```